# Java Snake Game Issue

Tags: java

So I have been trying to recreate the game Snake using Java, but I have run into a problem that I really don't understand.

The basis of the program is that there is an infinite loop that checks what direction the player has selected at one second intervals. The player can press buttons that change the value of "int direction" at any time, but the snake only moves in that direction after the timer on the loop is up.

The problem that I am having is that, while the program is executing, clicking on the buttons to change the direction does nothing. The change in direction will only take affect once the program has ended, and the player will not be able to guide the snake's movements.

Is there a way that I can correct this issue, Preferably without having to redesign the entire program?
.
.
.

Defining variables: Empty parts of the grid are assigned a value of 0 while ones occupied by the snake are given a value of 1

```
public static int x = 5;
public static int y = 5;

public static int grid[][] = new int[11][11];

public static int snakeLength = 1;

public static boolean alive = true;

public static int direction = 1;



public void paint(Graphics g)
{
            for(int r = 0; r<11; r++)
            {
                    for(int e = 0; e<11; e++)
                    {
                            grid[r][e] = 0;
                    }
            }



        grid[5][5] = 1;
```

The buttons I use to theoretically change the snake's direction

```
                Rectangle up = new Rectangle(250,550,50,50);
                Rectangle down = new Rectangle(250,650,50,50);
                Rectangle left = new Rectangle(200,600,50,50);
                Rectangle right = new Rectangle(300,600,50,50);

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(250,550,50,50);
        g.fillRect(250,650,50,50);
        g.fillRect(200,600,50,50);
        g.fillRect(300,600,50,50);     

}
```

The infinite loop and a series of branching loops to decide the next movement

up: direction = 1

down: direction = 2

left: direction = 3

right: direction = 4

```
  while(alive == true)
  {
                   try 
                   {
                   Thread.sleep(1000);
                   } 
                   catch(InterruptedException ex) 
                   {
                   Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                   }


        if(direction == 1)
        {
            if(grid[x][y - 1] == 0)
            {
                moveUp(g);

            }

            if(y  == -1)
            {
                fail(g);

            }

            if(grid[x][y - 1] == 1)
            {
                fail(g);

            }

            if(grid[x][y - 1] == 2)
            {
                y = y-1;
                food(g);

            }
        }
        if(direction == 2)
        {
            if(grid[x][y + 1] == 0)
            {

                moveDown(g);
            }

            if(y  == 11)
            {
                fail(g);
            }

            if(grid[x][y + 1] == 1)
            {
                fail(g);
            }

            if(grid[x][y + 1] == 2)
            {
                y = y+1;
                food(g);
            }
        }

        if(direction == 3)
        {
            if(grid[x - 1][y] == 0)
            {
                moveLeft(g);
            }

            if(x  == -1)
            {
                fail(g);
            }

            if(grid[x - 1][y] == 1)
            {
                fail(g);
            }

            if(grid[x - 1][y] == 2)
            {
                x = x-1;
                food(g);
            }
        }

        if(direction == 4)
        {
            if(grid[x + 1][y] == 0)
            {
                moveRight(g);
            }

            if(x == 11)
            {
                fail(g);
            }

            if(grid[x + 1][y] == 1)
            {
                fail(g);
            }

            if(grid[x + 1][y] == 2)
            {
                x = x+1;
                food(g);
            }
        }


    }
```

The method that I am having trouble with. It does not seem to change the value of direction until the program is already finished

```
public boolean mouseDown(Event e, int x, int y)
{
   if(up.inside(x,y))
   {
    direction = 1;
    System.out.println(direction);

   }
   if(down.inside(x,y))
   {
    direction = 2;
    System.out.println(direction);

   }
   if(left.inside(x,y))
   {
    direction = 3;
    System.out.println(direction);

   }
   if(right.inside(x,y))
   {
    direction = 4;
    System.out.println(direction);

   }

   return true;
```

}

Note that I have omitted the rest of my code for the sake of brevity, but I can provide it if it is in fact relevant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"The change in direction will only take affect once the program has ended"* - This doesn't make any sense to me. If the program is ended how do you know the change is taking effect? When you say **ended** I think that it's closed and gone. Maybe you could clarify?

Comment: Which method is your infinite loop get called from ultimately (`paint` or `main` perhaps)?

Comment: Instead of using 1, 2, 3 and 4 for your directions, you should use an enum which makes it explicit which direction is which, such as in http://pastebin.com/06yNW2TD

Comment: @Tim, I know that the changes are happening after the program finishes because of the print methods I included with the changes in direction. When looking at the output of the program during execution, the direction values aren't printed until the program crashes (which it does, but this is not the issue that I need help with) at which point all of the values, which should have been changed as I push the buttons, are all printed at once. Oddly, if I were to put a print method within the infinite loop, such as directly after the pause, The values are printed with the movements of the snake.

Comment: @Patashu I am calling the infinite loop from within the paint method. Sorry if that wasn't clear. All of the code I included is in the order in which it appears in my program. I only left out details that I thought would be confusing or distracting.